# Xcode 7.1 Storyboard hangs when viewing

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to develop a project that was built with Xcode 6.  When I open it with Xcode 7.1, my storyboard becomes  unresponsive.  Both the "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool"  and the Xcode processes spike the CPU.  If I look in Console.app, I see hundreds of lines that say..

```
Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool: assertion failed libxpc.dylib.
```

I am running OS X 10.11.1.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I've tried deleting caches, followed by complete uninstall/resinstall.   Nothing has fixed this issue.

Comment: File a bug with Apple. Only Apple can fix Xcode.